# How to search a student ID with user input and output with the student name and student ID in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to split a studentID and studentName in a file called Student.txt so I can have a user input to search for a specific student id in the file and display the student name and ID. But I don't know how to separate the studentID and student name in the file.

this is the content of my file

```
201707001 Michael_Tan 
201707002 Richard_Lee_Wai_Yong 
201707003 Jean_Yip 
201707004 Mark_Lee 
201707005 Linda_Wong 
201707006 Karen_Tan 
201707007 James_Bond 
201707008 Sandra_Smith 
201707009 Paul_Garcia
201707010 Donald_Lim
```

And this is my attempted code in Python

```
# user can search the studentID
searchStudent = input("Please enter a student ID: ")

# read the students file
with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
    studentFile = f.readlines()
    for student in studentFile:
        print(student)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer guys :)

Comment: got it thanks , new to stack overflow. sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `student.split(" ")` to split each line into id and name

```
searchStudent = input("Please enter a student ID: ")

with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
  studentFile = f.readlines()
      for student in studentFile:
          id, name = student.strip().split(" ", 1)
```

Comment: what does the .strip and the 1 in .split() mean?

Comment: it removes any space at the beginning and ending of each line

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split. In your case it strips the whitespace characters around each line then splits the line on the first found space character.

Comment: ohh wait I mis read your comment the `1` in `.split(" ", 1)` means that to split only the first occurrence. So it does not break syntax `id, name` if more space separated values are in the file
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Comment: why not use `student.split()` to split by whitespce so you don't need to `strip()`

Comment: to me strip before process data makes the data cleaner to process, and there would be extra code to detect empty strings after the `split(" ")` happen without `.strip()` @MoeA

Comment: Thats why you use `.split()` without a space which will split by whitespace and therefore there won't be any empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split each line using the space as a separator:

```
for line in studentFile:
    uid, student = line.strip().split(" ")
    print(student)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse every line and check if the Ids match. In other words, you need to split every line in two elements, id and name.
Check [split documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) page.